# Call insert icon function in PowerPoint programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, office-addins

I code a PowerPoint addin in C# and I would like to call the "native" function of PowerPoint that [insert icon](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-icons-in-microsoft-office-e2459f17-3996-4795-996e-b9a13486fa79) .

Do you know if it is possible to call this function programmatically ?

(I does not try to add objects to the slide and reproduce this function like interop library could do for example, but I wonder whether it is possible to call directly the add icon native function, that opens the same dialog box)

Comment: Interop is the automation mechanism / api of office, so (AFAIK) this is as close as you can get to the "native function".

Comment: @ bassfader : I want to know if it is possible to call the function, that open the dialog box etc exactly as same as clicking on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbars-executemso-method-office?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to get the icon button executed programmatically. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons and splitButtons. On failure it returns E_InvalidArg for an invalid IdMso, and E_Fail for controls that are not enabled or not visible. For example:

```
  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("Copy")
```

You can find the list of built-in control IDs in the following documents:

- [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

Comment: Great answer ! Unfortunatly I can't find my control in the list of idMso. I have read the entire (long) list of possible idMso - it seems to be absent - I think the function have been added recently so maybe it is not listed yet (list is 2 years ago and no update since). **But do you know if there is a possibility to insert a part of code to find which idMso I use if I click and then find the associated id ?**

Comment: You can try to find the required `idMso` value in the customize ribbon settings dialog in PowerPoint.